# How can I put title chapter at center of the line in tableofcontents?

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I am trying format `\tableofcontents` I want to put the chapter's titles `Topological spaces`at center and `Chapter 1`, ...like this picture
, but I can't get the result.

My code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{book}
\usepackage[unicode,bookmarksnumbered]{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\S\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}

\usepackage{sectsty} 

\allsectionsfont{\centering}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\itshape\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\itshape\nouppercase{\leftmark}}


\usepackage{tocloft,calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername\space}
\setlength{\cftchapnumwidth}{\widthof{\textbf{Appendix~999~}}}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\appendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\renewcommand{\protect\cftchappresnum}{\appendixname\space}%
  }%
}
\makeatother
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Topological spaces}
\section{Hello again}
    \subsection{Something}
\section{Something}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Something}
\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\appendix
\chapter{Hello again}
\section{Hello again}
\lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Hello again}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Off-topic: You're loading `hyperref` ways too early

Comment: No. I can not accept your answer. Because, the page of tableifcontents does not like my picture.

Comment: You asked for the centering of the title ... that's what my answer did.

Comment: I am sorry about my English. Please help me with my picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package to adjust the style and placing of division titles in the ToC.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{CHAPTER } % put CHAPTER before the number
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\centering} % center CHAPTER and number
\makeatletter
% start new line after the number, shift title so it is centered
\renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnumb}{%
    \\ \hspace{\@pnumwidth}\hspace{\@tocrmarg} \hfil\bfseries\large}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\hfill}
\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter} % no page numbers for chapters
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\cftparfillskip}

\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{\S\ } % put section symbol before section numbers

% then remainder of preamble and document
```

For more information read the manual (`> texdoc tocloft`).

[image]